# iPhone "Share" button

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there anything like the Android's "Share" button in iPhone?

I am just starting out in iOS development and do not have an iPhone (yet). The idea is to be able to select documents or images saved on the phone and use them in my app. I realize there is an ImagePickerController but that is not what I am looking for. I am also not looking for a third party component, rather something integrated into the OS similar to Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:  No.

You can [register your app to handle certain file types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application), and files of those types can then be opened by your app via UIActionSheets that may appear, for example, when you tap and hold on a file in an email.  You can also transfer files to your app via iTunes.  There's no 'file explorer' type feature in iOS where you can pull up a view of files saved to your phone.

For images, as you mentioned already, you must use UIImagePickerController.

Answer (score -1):

From documentation

> ### Sharing Files with the User
>
> Applications that want to make user data files accessible can do so using application file sharing. File sharing enables the application to expose the contents of its /Documents directory to the user through iTunes. The user can then move files back and forth between the device and a desktop computer. This feature does not allow your application to share files with other applications on the same device, though. To share data and files between applications, you must the pasteboard or a document interaction controller object.

You can read more here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW7